# Visual Basic create loop for counting even numbers

Tags: basic

The program requires input of positive numbers, and counts each even number using a loop function that doesn't count odds and ends if a O is input.

I'm not sure how to go about creating a loop or if I can use an `if` function within the loop.

```
Dim Count = 0
While (number mod 2 = 0) do
Count + 1 = Count
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually didn't  understand  the question very well but as far as concerned, if you dont want odd numbers to be included I suggest on count add 2 not one , since the count variable starts with zero do:

```
Dim Count+2
```

Btw when do you want the count to stop? At 2  And goes back to 0?
 If so then use the if statement

```
var Dim_count = 0; 
if(Dim_count == 0){Dim_count+2}
else if(Dim_count ==2){Dim_Count =0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you provide a sample input so we can work with actual code and guide you to the right solution.

If you receive the input as, let's say, array of numbers, you can simply loop trough it using `for` or `foreach` and add additional condition to check for 0 if you want to preliminary exit:

```
For Each number As Integer In numbers
    If (number mod 2 = 0) Then
       Count = Count + 1
    End If 

    If (number = 0) Then
       Exit For
    End If
Next
```

If you have existing code in which somehow `number` is reinitialized/redefined on each iteration already, then what you have is pretty close to what you need:

```
While (number <> 0)
    If (number mod 2 = 0) Then
       Count = Count + 1
    End If
End While
```

Answer (score 0):

Function counts even numbers:

```
REM function gets input, exits at 0 and adds positive even numbers.
DO
    INPUT X
    IF X = 0 THEN PRINT Y; " even numbers": END
    IF X > 0 THEN
        IF X / 2 = X \ 2 THEN Y = Y + 1
    END IF
LOOP
```

Answer (score 0):

I am completely unsure about this. just a guess...

```
Dim j as Integer

Dim i As integer

j = 0

i = 2

For i = 1 to 100

j = j+i

Print j

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow . Please explain your code instead of a plain code only . This way the OP can understand what is the use of your code and what it is for.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it in QBasic:

```
count% = 0
DO
  INPUT number%
  IF number% <= 0 THEN EXIT DO
  count% = count% - ((number% MOD 2) - 1)
LOOP
PRINT count%
```

I don't expect this to be much different in other BASIC dialects.

The key part does not require an `IF` statement:

> ```
> count% = count% - ((number% MOD 2) - 1)
> ```

If the number is **even** then `number% MOD 2` gives 0, and so we subtract -1 (0 - 1) from the *count%* which is tantamount to adding 1.
If the number is **odd** then `number% MOD 2` gives 1, and so we subtract 0 (1 - 1) from the *count%* which is tantamount to not changing it.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are getting numbers from some input, this is how you can do it. Have an infinite loop with `While True`, then for every number given from your input, check if its even using `number mod 2 = 0`. This will go on forever so you need to add some condition (another if statement) for it to stop the while loop. More information about while loops here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/while-end-while-statement

```
Dim Count = 0
While True do
  
  If (number mod 2 = 0) Then
    Count + 1 = Count
  End If 
End While
```